# Grid con bootstrap no es responsive, problema de diseño

Tags: html, css, responsive

Buen día, hice una simple página con este diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ver la vista movil de eso queda algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le saco el `height` a la clase `col-sm-4` se ve el texto horizontal sobre el texto vertical como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de esto es:

```css
.block2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#7596CB;
}
.msg {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color:white;
    text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    font-size: 500%;
    height:2em;
}
.block1 {
    background-color:#7596CB;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    text-align:center;
    width:600px;
    margin-left:-600px;
}
```

```html
<header>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</header>


<div class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height:650px !important;">
      <div class="block1">
        <table class="block2">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="msg">SERVICIOS</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8" style="height:650px !important; color:gray; font-size:3em;">01&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspRECURSOS HUMANOS<br/>02&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspGESTIÓN DE TALENTO<br/>03&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBUSCA TALENTOS<br/>04&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTRANSICIÓN PROFESIONAL<br/>05&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCAPACITACIÓN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo probé aisladamente y el problema persiste, en todo caso [subí el proyecto entero a MEGA mediante este enlace](https://mega.nz/#!M05GAKhK!Y_yXU1OZGLQu3wOVYEz8KqBz1EjgIzquOjBZpKmx1Qs) (el index es router.html)

El problema radica en que no lee correctamente el grid, también puede ser que exista conflicto con otras clases, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que es porque le estas diciendo que coja como height el valor que le pasas tú y le pones un !important, entonces cuando intentas hacer responsive mantiene ese height y por eso se superpone a la imagen.

Prueba a decirle que cuando el tamaño de la venta sea X pixeles, cambie el height

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        #id{
        height: Xpx;
}
```

A ver si te esto te sirve, cualquier cosa me dices.

Saludos

Comment: Que quieres lograr con ello, quiero decir quieres que el texto vertical se ponga horizontal o algo?

Comment: No, que cuando la ventana tenga un ancho de 'x' pixeles, el height del div cambie. Para que se baje y no se superponga.

Comment: La idea es que se vea como la primera imagen solo con la vista de celular:/ al implementar lo que mencionas solo se sigue viendo como la segunda imagen

Comment: El responsive consiste en eso, en ajustar los componentes al tamaño de la ventana, si quieres que se vea a la derecha, tendrías que ajustar el tamaño de la fuente y muchas cosas o hacer un menú desplegable cuando la ventana sea modo teléfono. No se alomejor te estoy entendiendo mal.

Comment: @Sebastián es sencillo creo, lo que debnerias hacer poner un tamñao menos en pantallas sm es decir que el texto (sevicios) ocupe 1 o 2 celdas y el otro ocupe las demas

Comment: Cambio row-fluid por row